# Bluetooth low energy APIs in java

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with Bluetooth Low energy . Is there  any APIs  or open source SDK for BLE in java ? My goal is to  run my pc as a BLE peripheral . And what I have tried is , just searched for the APIs for some time and I have found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But dont know how to implement.

**Edit:**  I also have something [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , I think which used to create the characteristic and services . As per my understanding there is no driver required in window8 as it has inbuilt support . But i am confused with which library to add in to run this code.

Comment: How is the question related to Android? Have You seen this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EC5-cEbr520&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9WGUwq2gQ-coU3fSyexgOx talk?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no library yet. Probably the best way is to build a JNI wrapper around the Windows 8 C++ library. Why not start an open source project?

As soon as you have the low level there is a nice little helper library to work with the GATT profiles: https://github.com/movisens/SmartGattLib

> SmartGattLib is a Java library that simplifies the work with Bluetooth SMART devices (a.k.a Bluetooth Low Energy in Bluetooth 4.0). It provides all UUIDs of the adopted GATT specification and an convenient way to interpret the characteristics (e.g. Heart Rate, BatteryLevel). The library has no dependencies and can be use with every Bluetooth SMART stack.