# Java (J2SE) Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)

Tags: java, linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect to a Bluetooth Low-Energy (BLE) Sensor using Java. So far I searched for a library that interfaces with the BlueZ stack on my Linux.

The only free library I found for Java was Bluecove but it seems, that they don't implement BLE.
I checked if my BT dongle was working and recognizing the sensor using Linux command line tools

```
sudo hcitool lescan

gatttool -i hci0 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -I
```

and it worked without problems.

After that I tried the Bluecove example for DeviceDiscovery but my sensor didn't show up instead it scanned for normal BT devices. I couldn't find a way to scan for BLE devices.

Doing further research I came to the conclusion that Bluecove just implements JSR-82.
If I'm not mistaken this standard is older than BLE and therefore doesn't implement it.

Are there any alternatives to Bluecove that support BLE in Java? I mean there should be because Android has no problems (in newer versions) to communicate with BLE devices.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bluetooth low energy APIs in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825138/bluetooth-low-energy-apis-in-java)

Comment: The linked topic is about Windows which is using a different Bluetooth stack. I agree that the topics are kind of similar because as soon as there is a low level connection SmartGATTLib could be used

Comment: @sgiessmann did u figured out, if it is possible to use SmartGATTLib, to communicate with BLE over e.g. a BLE dongle? As far as I know SmartGATTLib is developed for smartphone, isnt it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After looking into this a while later I found an answer named TinyB.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/java-for-bluetooth-le-apps

TinyB is a BluetoothLE implementation by Intel and it features a Java SDK.
So far I've been able to achieve everything I tried.

Hope this helps others stumbling across this topic.

Comment: was you able to listen for advertisments with TinyB lib, or how do you implemented this?

Comment: This should no longer the accepted answer since the link is no longer valid.

Comment: _TinyB_'s home page is [http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/tinyb/java/](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/tinyb/java/)

Comment: GitHub - https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb and YouTube demo for it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsC0VXVMS9Y

Answer (score 1):

An interesting option is using [Kura Bluetooth LE APIs](https://eclipse.github.io/kura/dev/bluetooth-le-apis.html), which are built on top of the TinyB library.